# Having problem reading a text file in Python

Tags: python, file-handling

I am trying to read a text file.
But it is not printing anything on the screen

This simple program works fine.

```
with open("This.txt",'r') as file:
  for line in file:
    print(line)
```

output:-

```
Harry Potter,2

Dragon's Nest,1

Happy Life,1
```

But than I added if else statement in it.
When I run it, I am not getting any output.
My code :-

```
with open("This.txt",'r') as file:
    if file.read()=='':
        print("File empty")
    else:
        for line in file:
          print(line)
```

output ->

What could be the problem?

Comment: After your `file.read()`, the `fp` position is set to the end of the file, so, in your `else`, you have to reset the `fp` to the beginning of your file by adding one line `file.seek(0)` before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `file.read()`, Python reads the file till the end. So, after calling the `read()` function, when Python reaches the `else` statement, it returns an empty string, since it is at the end of the file. To make Python go back to the start of the file, you need to use `file.seek(0)`. Modified code:

```
with open("This.txt",'r') as file:
    if file.read()=='':
        print("File empty")
    else:
        file.seek(0) #Add this
        for line in file:
          print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely wasteful to call `file.read()`, which reads the content of the *entire file* into the memory, causing a serious impact to performance and memory usage when the file is large, when all you want out of it is just to test if it is empty.

A much more efficient approach would be to call the [`file.tell`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) method after reading the file line by line to see if the file pointer moved at all to a non-zero position:

```
with open('This.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
    if not file.tell():
        print('File empty')
```